# React share all methods inside a function component that might interact with the state between another function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to share **ALL** the methods in a function component between another function component, even if the method interacts with the state, here's what I've got working so far:

```js
// App.js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import FooColor from './components/FooColor.js';
import BarColor from './components/BarColor.js';

const App = () => {
    const fooChangeColorToRed = useRef(() => {});
    const fooChangeColorToGreen = useRef(() => {});
    const fooChangeColorToBlue = useRef(() => {});

    const barChangeColorToRed = useRef(() => {});
    const barChangeColorToGreen = useRef(() => {});
    const barChangeColorToBlue = useRef(() => {});

    return (
        <div>
            <FooColor
                fooChangeColorToRed={fooChangeColorToRed}
                fooChangeColorToBlue={fooChangeColorToBlue}
                fooChangeColorToGreen={fooChangeColorToGreen}
                barChangeColorToRed={barChangeColorToRed}
                barChangeColorToGreen={barChangeColorToGreen}
                barChangeColorToBlue={barChangeColorToBlue}
            />
            <BarColor
                fooChangeColorToRed={fooChangeColorToRed}
                fooChangeColorToBlue={fooChangeColorToBlue}
                fooChangeColorToGreen={fooChangeColorToGreen}
                barChangeColorToRed={barChangeColorToRed}
                barChangeColorToGreen={barChangeColorToGreen}
                barChangeColorToBlue={barChangeColorToBlue}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

```js
// FooColor.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const FooColor = (props) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        color: 'No color picked yet',
    });

    const changeColorToRed = () => {
        setState({
            color: 'red',
        });
    };

    const changeColorToGreen = () => {
        setState({
            color: 'green',
        });
    };

    const changeColorToBlue = () => {
        setState({
            color: 'blue',
        });
    };

    props.fooChangeColorToRed.current = changeColorToRed;
    props.fooChangeColorToGreen.current = changeColorToGreen;
    props.fooChangeColorToBlue.current = changeColorToBlue;

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Foo</div>
            Foo Color: {state.color}
            <br />
            <button onClick={props.barChangeColorToRed.current}>Change bar color to red</button>
            <button onClick={props.barChangeColorToGreen.current}>Change bar color to green</button>
            <button onClick={props.barChangeColorToBlue.current}>Change bar color to blue</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FooColor;
```

```js
// BarColor.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const BarColor = (props) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        color: 'No color picked yet',
    });

    const changeColorToRed = () => {
        console.log('hi');
        setState({
            color: 'red',
        });
    };

    const changeColorToGreen = () => {
        setState({
            color: 'green',
        });
    };

    const changeColorToBlue = () => {
        setState({
            color: 'blue',
        });
    };

    props.barChangeColorToRed.current = changeColorToRed;
    props.barChangeColorToGreen.current = changeColorToGreen;
    props.barChangeColorToBlue.current = changeColorToBlue;

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Bar</div>
            Bar Color: {state.color}
            <br />
            <button onClick={props.fooChangeColorToRed.current}>Change foo color to red</button>
            <button onClick={props.fooChangeColorToGreen.current}>Change foo color to green</button>
            <button onClick={props.fooChangeColorToBlue.current}>Change foo color to blue</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default BarColor;
```

This has a few issues, sharing more than 10 methods or so becomes very unreadable. Also, the "BarColor" component initially wouldn't be able to call methods in the "FooColor" component until a method is called in the "FooColor" component. This might be because of the order they are placed in inside of the App component

Is there a more efficient and readable way to do the exact same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a custom hook with as much shared logic as possible
that returns all of your data and needed methods?

**For example:**

```js
/* color.jsx */

export function useColor() {

  // Our shared state:
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    color: 'No color picked yet',
  });

  // Our methods:
  const changeColorToRed = () => {
    setState({
      color: 'red',
    });
  };

  const changeColorToGreen = () => {
    setState({
      color: 'green',
    });
  };

  const changeColorToBlue = () => {
    setState({
      color: 'blue',
    });
  };

  return {
    state,
    changeColorToRed,
    changeColorToGreen,
    changeColorToBlue,
  }
}
```

So basically, we'll have this shared hook containing a shared `state` and methods,
and we'll `return` everything we want to use in the relevant comps.

**For example:**

```js
/* FooColor.jsx */

const FooColor = () => {
  const { state, changeColorToRed, changeColorToGreen, changeColorToBlue } = useColor();

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Foo</div>
      Foo Color: {state.color}
      <br />
      <button onClick={changeColorToRed}>Change foo color to red</button>
      <button onClick={changeColorToGreen}>Change foo color to green</button>
      <button onClick={changeColorToBlue}>Change foo color to blue</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then you can import and use it in the exact same way in `BarColor`.

In this example we get a clean result without the need for `useRef` or even `props` of any kind in this case.

For more info, you can check out the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) about custom hooks.

Also, the use-case here is a little vague so I hope that I understood your needs correctly.
Let me know if you need some more help with this.

---

### Update:

If we need 2 separate states for each component color,
we can simply manage separate states in the shared hook.

**Example:**

```js
  // Either like this:
  const [fooColor, setFooColor] = useState('No color picked yet');
  const [barColor, setBarColor] = useState('No color picked yet');

  // Or like this (my personal preference):
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    fooColor: 'No color picked yet',
    barColor: 'No color picked yet',
  });

  // Then we can add a parameter in order to avoid function duplication:
  const changeColorToRed = (comp) => {
    switch (comp) {
      case 'foo':
        setState({
          // Spread the existing contents of the state (`barColor` in this case):
          ...state,
          fooColor: 'red',
        });

      case 'bar':
        setState({
          ...state,
          barColor: 'red',
        });

      default:
        console.error('Non-existent comp passed');
    }
  };
```

Comment: I'm trying to change state of BarColor.js from the FooColor.js component using the methods in BarColor.js and vice-versa, so when you click on the button in FooColor.js, only the state of BarColor.js changes and the text is updated in BarColor.js only, and the state in FooColor.js is not affected

Comment: Also, if you want to take it up a notch, get comfortable with [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). Here, for example, it would have allowed you to restrict the value of the `comp` parameter to only "foo" and "bar", along with a bunch of other useful features.